# Question about prepositions in English idioms

Tags: syntax, english, prepositions

I have noticed that many idioms in English include a fixed preposition at the same time that the complement of the preposition is free, e.g.

> a. light a fire under X
>
> b. carry a torch for X
>
> c. cast a pall on X
>
> d. keep in touch with X

The verb-preposition combination is fixed in these cases, whereas the complement of the preposition is free (as indicated by the use of X). One can vary the complement, e.g. *light a fire under John/you/the students/* etc. In contrast, there seem to be no idioms in which the verb and complement noun of the preposition are fixed at the same time that the preposition itself is free, *light a fire above/beside/behind John* -- only the literal readings possible here.

Why is the preposition so special? What does this situation reveal about idiosyncratic verb-preposition combinations?

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean. The noun phrases aren’t substitutable either. We don’t ‘light a pall under’ or ‘carry a fire for’ someone any more than we ‘light a fire behind’ or ‘cast a pall with’ someone. In idioms, the _entire thing_ is fixed – verbs, noun phrases, prepositions, adverbs. That’s why idioms are considered _fixed_ expressions. The prepositions are in fact probably the least fixed part of the expression, since you can actually say things like, “light a fire in [someone’s] ass” or “it’s cast a pall over the whole village” with a different preposition.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I think OP gets at the fact that the prepositional object isn’t fixed.

Comment: Nouns, verbs, and other types of words that are modified by prepositional phrases are often said to **govern** individual prepositions. For instance, _listen_ and _look_ are both intransitive verbs, but they can be made into "verb + preposition" constructions that are transitive: _listen to_ and _look at_. But only with those prepositions, which they govern. The object of a preposition may be anything, but which preposition gets used frequently depends on what words it's modifying.

Comment: I still don’t quite understand what you’re asking here. The open noun you’re talking about is the object of the preposition (the Xes in your examples), correct? Why would you expect the prepositions to be open and their object open to fixed under any circumstance? There are cases where you can choose freely between two or three different prepositions in a particular idiom, but I don’t see any reason why prepositions should be expected to be open, rather than closed, a priori.

Comment: I don’t really see how catenas can help here, and be aware that it is not a widely used concept. These constructions are usually called [phrasal verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phrasal_verbs). As a verb-preposition combination becomes more and more frequent, they start to form what you might eventually analyze as a single verb, i.e., the preposition (and possibly other items) is incorporated into the verb. It is far more common that a single V-P combination becomes overly frequent than that a V-O combination does, so the P becomes fixed, whereas the Object doesn’t.

Comment: Though there are V-O examples as well (*kick the bucket*), they are probably just not as common.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet. This question should be re-opened. I have edited it for clarity. It concerns which word combinations can (or cannot) be assigned idiosyncratic meaning. The issue is important for our understanding of the interface between syntax and semantics.

Comment: @Tim I’ve voted to reopen, though I doubt the premise that there are no idioms with variant prepositions is actually quite true. I can’t think of any examples right now (I just get out of bed, which may have something to do with it), but I’m sure there are idioms which include a specific noun in their specification, but whose preposition can vary. Not fully openly, of course, but in cases where the noun is open, it’s not usually completely open either (e.g., we can cast a pall on/over the situation, but we can’t cast a pall on the kettle/rainbow/spider).

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet. Verbal idioms are predicates, and predicates semantically select their arguments. Hence the fact that something cannot cast a pall over the kettle/rainbow/spider is perfectly consistent with the nature of predicates in general. If you can come up with any idioms where the verb and noun are fixed but the preposition can vary, please post it/them. I am not aware of any such idioms, and have argued extensively in my writings that no such idioms exist.

Comment: @TimOsborne and what is your definition of an idiom? E.g. https://benjamins.com/catalog/lis.36

Comment: Examples: *light a fire under someone* is a fixed idiom but *light a fire under the rocks* is not. >*carry a torch for a cause* is an idiom, *carry a torch for the parade* is not. So, your premise is **faulty**.